# How to run Spatial Query using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-query

I have a shapefile of a forest inventory of the uk. I want to find out the total area of woodland within a 60km radius of a specific point. I have added a layer for the point and added a 60 km buffer. so i now want to know the total area of woodland within this areas.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Please be more specific, both with the question and your problem description. What software do you use? ArcGIS or QGIS, or something else? Can you store (spatial) data in a database? Please edit your question!!!

Comment: Im using ArcGis 10.1. What do you mean store spatial data in a database- sadly i need things in lehmans!

Comment: Are you loading shapefiles or a geodatabsae from a directory in to ArcMap? or are you connecting to a database?

Comment: i'm adding them as shapefiles

Answer (score 1):

You should look after the "intersect" command with your software (e.g. [QGIS](http://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/geo-processing-in-qgis/) or [ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000z000000). This will create new geometries at the intersection between your buffer and your woodland polygons. Then you compute the area of your polygons and you summarize your table based on the ID's of your point buffers and the value of your land cover field.

Comment: Thank you- I tried intersecting the buffer and the woodland polygons but it came up with errors saying "empty output generated" and "no records within table"

Comment: I guess you created your buffers in an edit session. Make sure you saved your edit before using intersect. If not, try "repair geometry" first.

Comment: You likely have an empty output because there were no intersecting features.  The inputs for the tool should be the forest shapefile and the 60 km buffer polygon shapefile. Do you happen to be using the point feature as well.  Visually, I am assuming that the forest and buffer shapefiles overlap?  Check that both shapefiles are in the same projection.